# How to scroll a fixed div when I resize the browser window

Tags: html, css

I created a `position: fixed` `div`, which must be always on the top, with `width: 900px`, now I have the following problem, when I resize the browser window to a size least than `900px` my `div` is cropped and i can't even scroll it because the scroll bar doesnt appear.
How can I resolve?

The code is the following:
`<body>
 <div class= "bar"><div class="inner_div"></div></div>
</body>`

Now the css

`.bar { position: fixed;
height: 60px; width: 900px; border: 2px solid;
}`

```
.inner_div {position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 2px; border: 2px solid;  width: 100px; height: 15px;}
```

Trying this code you'll see that if your browser window gets less than 900px the bar is cropped and there isn't way to scroll it and to see the inner_div.

Comment: have you used overflow:visible ?

Comment: It is always best to post your code using the "Code Sample" button available when posting.

Comment: It's bad practice to use fixed divs now because of mobile devices. Zooming in on the page will almost always break the layout. Use relative positioning or absolute if you really need to.

Comment: May be relevant: http://qtax.se/css/centered-modal-popup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure some browsers only use non-fixed elements to determine the width of your content. Adding something like this at the bottom of your page should get you your scroll bar `<div style="width:900px;"></div>`

Previously I didn't mention that the spacing div can't be empty or has to have a height, so adding a non-breaking space or a 1px height to it will make it fill the width.

Full Code Example:http://jsfiddle.net/8LnBr/

```
<style>
.bar { position: fixed; height: 60px; width: 900px; border: 2px solid; }
.inner_div {position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 2px; border: 2px solid;  width: 100px; height: 15px;}
.spanner{width:900px; height:1px;}
</style>
<body>
 <div class= "bar">
  <div class="inner_div"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="spanner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand, where should I put the <div>?

Comment: inside the body tag, outside of any other divs.

Comment: @user2262522 - edited my answer with a full working code example.

Comment: I have just copied the code, but still not working, when I resize the browser window the inner_div becomes hidden, the scroll appears but i can scroll only the div scaper (?banner).

Comment: @user2262522 - I screwed up the class name when I copied it into Stack overflow. Just change the class in the div to 'spanner' instead of 'spacer'

Comment: I know, I had already changed it, but still not working. I think I didn't explain myself very good

Comment: What browser are you testing in? That JS fiddle link works in FF, Chrome, and IE9

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. The problem is that a fixed bar can't be scrolled and I want to find a way to do it, with the code you gave me I see a scroll bar but the fixed div doesn't move

Comment: Ok, I totally misunderstood what you were looking for then. What you want isn't possible with a fixed div. Fixed means that it isn't going to care about scroll position or window size. It's going to stay fixed in size and place..